# How to call function from one class from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0

I need a little help here.

I have created a class name helpdesk dashboard, what I need to call a function from one class to another.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinControls;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;

namespace HELPDISK
{
    public partial class HELPDESK_DASHBOARD : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {
        public HELPDESK_DASHBOARD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void loadassign()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have another class name assign

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinControls;

namespace HELPDISK
{
    public partial class AssignForm : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {

    }

    public void loadnames()
    {
        // I have to call the function loadassign here
    }
}
```

How to call the function loadassign from class helpdesk to class assignform?

Comment: Make your loadnames function public from private access!!!

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged 'asp.net' - Telerik Radform is a Windows Forms thing. However, LolCoder is correct - make `loadassign` public..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply create a new object from `HELPDESK_DASHBOARD`

```
HELPDESK_DASHBOARD db = new HELPDESK_DASHBOARD();
```

and then call function

```
db.loadassign();
```

or you can do that by using openForms like below

```
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["HELPDESK_DASHBOARD"] != null)
{
    (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["HELPDESK_DASHBOARD"] as HELPDESK_DASHBOARD).loadassign();
}
```

I advise you to use the second option because it just open existed form instead of creating a new one.

hopefully this can help you.

Comment: my pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

you can create  `HELPDESK_DASHBOARD` class object

```
HELPDESK_DASHBOARD objhelpdesk=new HELPDESK_DASHBOARD ();
```

and call your function `loadassign();`

```
objhelpdesk.loadassign();
```